# Does there exist an analytic function such that $|f(z)|=|\sin z|$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an analytic function $f(z)$ defined on $\Omega$ such that $|f(z)|=|\sin z|$ for all $z\in\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$? Well I guess if there is a constant $c$ with $|c|=1$ and $f(z)=c\sin(z)$ for all $z\in\Omega$, am I right?

Comment: What is $\Omega$?  If it is an open connected set then $f= \omega \cdot \sin$ for some constant $\omega$ with $|\omega| = 1$.  If for example $\Omega$ is the unit circle then there are more possibilities.

Comment: thanx exactly, Omega is a domain, so open connected.

Comment: then $f(z)/\sin(z)$ must be constant by the maximum modulus principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is such a function, and assuming that $\Omega$ is a connected open set, then $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\sin(z)}$ has removable singularities at the zeros of $\sin$. Thus $g$ extends uniquely to define an analytic function (I'll still call it $g$) with $|g(z)|\equiv 1$ on $\Omega$.  Since $\Omega$ is connected, this [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147834/why-a-holomorphic-function-with-constant-magnitude-must-be-constant) that your "guess" not only gives correct examples (as mentioned by JLA), it gives all examples.

Answer (score 3):

Well $\sin z$ itself is analytic, so you can just let $f(z)=\sin z$. But maybe that's too easy...but yes, take $c=e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, and your answer is correct. Depending on what $\Omega$ is, there could be other solutions.

Comment: But depending on what $