# $f,g,h$ be a holomorphic functions such that $|f(z)|+|g(z)|+|h(z)|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a connected open set, and let $f,g,h:U\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic functions such that $$|f(z)|+|g(z)|+|h(z)|=1$$ for all $z\in U$. How does one prove that $f,g,h$ are constant functions?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $U$? Does it hold for only two functions satisfying an analogous condition? and what about only one function?

Comment: of course, $U$ should be open (for holomorphicity) and then connected, otherwise this is not true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[We recall the following identity for harmonic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147844/18240)
$$\Delta (u^2 + v^2) = 2(|\nabla u|^2 + |\nabla v|^2).$$
Considering a more general problem, suppose $$\sum_{i=1}^n |f_i(z)| =1$$
for all $z\in U$ for some set of holomorphic functions $f_i$.
Working locally, we may assume that $f_i= g_i^2$ for some holomorphic functions $g_i=u_i+iv_i$. Then taking the Laplacian of both sides yields
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |\nabla u_i|^2 + |\nabla v_i|^2 = 0.$$
Hence the gradients of the real and imaginary parts of $u_i$ and $v_i$ vanish for all $i$, so each $f_i$ must be constant.

Comment: But $|f_i(z)|$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @felipeuni |g^2|=|g|^2=u^2+v^2, which is.

Comment: So $g$ is the square root of $f$ but if $f$ is zero anywhere the square root is not differentiable in which case $g$ would not be holomorphic. So your answer assumes that $f,g,h$ are non-zero on $U$. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer You only need to show they're zero on some open disk in $U$, and it's not hard to see there's one that will avoid all the zeros of the functions.

Comment: @Potato Ok, right, of course it's enough to show they are constant on an open subset. I believe you but I don't yet see how to get the open subset. Concretely, if they are not constant each one has some open subset on which they are non zero, say $U_f, U_g$ and $U_h$. How do we guarantee that their intersection is non empty?

Comment: @RudytheReindeer For each function, its set of zeros is discrete in $U$. So the union of these sets is too.