# $|f(z)|=|f(z_0)|$ implies $f(z)=f(z_0)$ for all $z\in\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Update**

I'm trying to understand the author's proof of the Maximum Modulus Principle:

**Let $f$ be analytic and non-constant in the domain $D$. Then $|f(z)|$ does not attain a maximum value at any point $z_0$ in $D$. In other words, there is no point $z_0$ in $D$ such that for all $z$ in $D$, $|f(z)|\le|f(z_0|$.**

Now, I've followed the author's proof, understanding all the steps, then arriving at the result

$$|f(z_0)|=|f(z_0+re^{i\theta})|\quad\text{for all}\quad 0\le r\le R\quad\text{and}\quad 0\le \theta\le 2\pi$$

which means that $|f(z)|$ is a constant for all $z$ in $\overline{D}_R(z_0)$.

Now, by a previous theorem in the textbook, if the modulus of a function is constant on a closed disk, then the function is also constant in that closed disk, another theorem that I've proved.

Then he states that $f(z)=f(z_0)$ for all $z$ in the closed disk $\overline{D}_R(z_0)$.

This is the step I cannot understand. For example, why can't it be $f(z)=-f(z_0)$?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not true. For example, define $f(z)$ to be $1$ on the real line, and $-1$ off the real line. Then $|f(z)|$ is constant over all of $\Bbb{C}$, but not constant on any open disk intersecting the real line.

Comment: It holds for holomorphic $f$ by maximum modulus

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147834/why-a-holomorphic-function-with-constant-magnitude-must-be-constant).

Comment: @Conrad  I've updated my question.

Comment: @user744868 I've updated my question.

Comment: @Riley I've updated my question.

Comment: $f$ is continuous so $f(z)=-f(z_0)$ implies $f(z_0)=-f(z_0)$, so $f(z_0)=0$ and then $f(z)=f(z_0)$ again