# For $R>0$ , $D_R=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} | |z|< R \}$. Let, $f,g: D_R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic functions such that never are 0 in $D_R$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

For $R>0$ , $D_R=\{ z\in \mathbb{C} | |z|< R  \}$. Let, $f,g: D_R \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic functions such that never are 0 in $D_R$. Show that:

If for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$,  $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ then, there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda|=1$ and $f=\lambda g$.

Since f, g are analytic in $D_R$ then, satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If $f=u+iv$ and $g=p+iq$ then:

$u^2+v^2=p^2+q^2$

but I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: It might be helpful to write $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ in terms of $f, \ \overline{f}, \ g$, and $\overline{g}$.  You also might want to use $|f(z)|=|\overline{f(z)}|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $\frac{f}{g}$ is analytic in $D_R$ and has constant norm $1$. But [an analytic function with constant norm is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147834/why-a-holomorphic-function-with-constant-magnitude-must-be-constant/147837).