# Show that if $f$ has no zeros in $U$, then $f$ must be a constant. (Use maximum modulus principle).

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \overline{U} → C$ is holomorphic where $|f(z)| = 1$ for $|z| = 1$. Show that if $f$ has no zeros in $U$, then $f$ must be a constant. (Use maximum modulus principle). Where $U$ is open unit disk.

I checked that this statememt was proved on the unit disk, but I couldn't prove that $f$ is a constant in $U$. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is wrong for $f(z) = 1/z$ on $U = \{ 1/2 < |z|< 2 \}$. Did you forget to mention some additional conditions? Could it be that $U$ is assumed to *contain the unit disk?*

Comment: What is $U$? As it stands, this is very false.

Comment: $U=\{z:|z|<1\}$, $\overline{U}=\{z:|z| \leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the maximum modulus principle, we have
$$ \sup_{z\in U} |f(z)|\leq 1.$$
Since $f$ has no zero in $U$, it follows that $1/f$ is holomorphic in $U$. Moreover, $1/|f|=1$ on $\partial U$. Hence it follows from the maximum modulus principle that
$$ \sup_{z\in U} (1/|f|) \leq 1.$$
Hence $|f(z)|=1$ for all $z\in U$. Since $U$ is a domain, $f$ is constant (see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147834/why-a-holomorphic-function-with-constant-magnitude-must-be-constant)).